# What does the parameters mean in Webpack's HMR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

Why should we put parameter into `module.hot.accept()`? If we put nothing, `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` works, but also React component will lose its state data.
If we use `react-hot-loader`, we should put parameters to `accept` method, but I don't know what the first parameter means, and also why the
callback should `require` again and get the `default`?

```jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {AppContainer} from 'react-hot-loader';

import getRouter from './src/router';

const boot = (elements)=> {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            {elements}
        </AppContainer>
        , document.getElementById('app'));
}

let rs = getRouter();
boot(rs); //first render

// render after source code change
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./src/router', ()=> {
        boot(require('./src/router').default())
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The first parameter is a observed,
it is a component, if it or its child component was changed,
callback function(the second parameter) will be call, and we
should require the component again and drop the old one, then
render(replace with new one) the new component to the DOM.